# how to interpret きみがそうだったように?

Tags: translation, song-lyrics

This sentence is from a song's lyric *歌に形はないけれど* (Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CV5wVHjMfQ&feature=youtu.be&t=136).

How to understand that?

There are two Chinese translations:

> 你为我做过的一样 (It's just like you did for me)

> 你是这样的温柔 (You're so tender)

They're not same and both can't correspond to the original Japanese sentence directly.

What's the real meaning of that? or how to interpret that?

Comment: I just visited here and going to check your link from now... Be patient, this site isn't as hyperactive as Stackoverflow that people crowd about a question in an hour or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the context:

> 僕は歌うよ
> 笑顔をくれた君が泣いてるとき
> ほんの少しだけでもいい
> 君の支えになりたい
>
> 僕が泣いてしまった日に
> 君がそうだったように

You can see the perspective is swapped symmetrically between the former and the latter stanzas.

> (1) 僕 (subject) : 君が泣いてるとき : 君の支えになりたい
> (2) 君 (subject) : 僕が泣いてしまった日 : **そうだった**

Thus it is natural to think that そうだった could be replaced, with correct tense and mood, by 僕の支えになった "was/became my anchor" (as a whole, 君が僕の支えになったように).

So, I don't think either translation you cited is wrong in this context, except the second one lacks explicit translation of ～ように "just like", if I have to nitpick.